# Surface Area of Curve about y-axis

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to rotate the curve
$$
\frac{1}{4} x^{2}-\frac{1}{2} \ln x
$$
with $$
1 \leq x \leq 2
$$
about the y-axis. I know the formula for this is:
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\left(2 \pi f(y) \sqrt{1+\left(f^{\prime}(y)\right)^{2}}\right) d y
$$
The only difficulty I'm having is getting the formula in terms of x. How should I go about this?

Comment: you just replace $x$ with $-x$ and you get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

There is solution to the problem but it is quite complex.

Since $x>1$ rewrite
$$y=\frac 14 x^2-\frac 12 \log(x)=\frac 14 x^2-\frac 14 \log(x^2)$$ The inverse is given in terms of Lambert function
$$x=\sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)}$$
$$\frac {dx}{dy}=-\frac{2 \sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)}}{W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)+1}$$ All of that makes the integrand to be
$$2\pi\sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)} \sqrt{1-\frac{4 W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4
   y}\right)}{\left(W_{-1}\left(-e^{-4 y}\right)+1\right){}^2}}$$ which (thanks to a CAS) can be integrated (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B-ProductLog%5B-1%2C+-E%5E%28-4*y%29%5D%5D*++Sqrt%5B1+-+%284*ProductLog%5B-1%2C+-E%5E%28-4*y%29%5D%29%2F%281+%2B+ProductLog%5B-1%2C+-E%5E%28-4*y%29%5D%29%5E2%5D%2Cy%5D)).